# Can I copy files to a VM when I used ESX?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-tools

I use ESX infrastructure and installed VM Tools on my VM.
When I used VM Workstation I could copy files and text between my computer to the VM that run on it.
Can I do the same when the VM placed on ESX server and not on my computer? (With VM Tools for example?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.
If you can't you need to check isolation properties of VM.
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1026437